# What can the Arcana do to stop the Sharona military

Tags: hells-gate

If you read the second *Hell's Gate* book, *Hell Hath No Fury*, the Union of
Arcana is in a bad place. They lost control of the Hell Gate; their invasion force is completely cut off from resupply. Most of their dragons on the front line are dead. And Sharona is on the verge of launching on invasion of their occupied worlds with their new mechanized army.

Given the Arcana level of magic/technology, the resources they have at the frontier universes and the resources they could realistically be sent to reinforce the frontier, is there a strategy they could employ that could theoretically at least prevent Sharona from reaching their more populated universes further down the chain?

Comment: Assuming this isn't something that will be covered in an upcoming book, you could improve this question by making it a bit more focused.  There may be many "possible" answers, depending strongly on what various people might consider "possible."  You should try to constrain this somewhat by more concretely setting the parameters of your question; broadly speaking what is and is not on the table?  You might find [the post about subjective questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) useful in matching your question to how the site works.

Answer (score 1):

This Isn’t a strategy, but I think it might be an answer. You will remember that as the couple moves further and further into the other universe, their magic abilities diminish. So it is an open question, and a possible answer, what will happen as an entire army moves deeper and deeper into another universe. Is the diminishment affect a question of distance? Or of time? Or possibly even of magic use?

It could be that entire army moving in like that would totally diminish their magic. That seems an answer that the author is foreshadowing.